# NHibernate IUserType Query Generating "= null" Instead of "is null"

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

It's generating `"= null"` instead of `"is null"` when querying a property using an `IUserType`. Gist of the biz rule is a null value in the database == `OrderStatus.InProcess`. Is there a work around or am I just doing it wrong?

Here is my `IUserType` implementation:

```
public class OrderStatusTypeMapper2 : IUserType
{
    public  object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var name = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return OrderStatus.InProcess;

        return (OrderStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatus), name);
    }

    public  void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            return;
        }

        var status = (OrderStatus)value;

        if (status == OrderStatus.InProcess)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            return;
        }

        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, status.ToString(), index);
    }

    public  SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { NHibernateUtil.String.SqlType }; }
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(OrderStatus); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Mapped with:

```
 Map(x => x.Status).CustomType<OrderStatusTypeMapper2>();
```

And then my usage:

```
 var results = session.Query<Order>()
            .Where(x => x.Status == OrderStatus.InProcess);

 Console.WriteLine(results.Count());
```

Which generates:

```
select
    cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ 
from
    sales orderentit0_ 
where
    orderentit0_.Status=@p0;
@p0 = NULL [Type: String (4000)]
```

And finally the desired (or similar) output:

```
select
    cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ 
from
    sales orderentit0_ 
where
    orderentit0_.Status is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you're asking is, how do you check if the `Status` column is null, this should do the trick:

```
var results = session.QueryOver<Order>()
     .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Status).IsNull;
```

Nhibernate won't pick up on the fact that your're using `null` and thus won't rewrite the sql, you have to explicitly use `WhereRestrictionOn()`and `IsNull`.

Comment: That worked, ultimately guess I could remove the IUserType, change Status to nullable and check for null everywhere instead of the readable `InProcess`, which I'd rather not. Going to sit on this. 

If this app was greenfield I would just change database data to not null, but I'm dealing with a *very* brownfield app.

Comment: Yea, know how you're feeling. Wish I had any more ideas but I think you might have to bite the bullet and do manual null-checking instead. Good luck!